# IE 11 stopped working after a power failure - Windows 8.1 64 bit

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

There was a power failure. For some reason this specific windows feature stopped working. The laptop remained on because it had a charge. However, now IE says "your last browsing session unexpectedly closed, restore." Whenever you click anything inside the internet explorer window it will not work.
Steps taken so far: restarting the PC, turn Internet Explorer on and off, troubleshoot internet explorer performance abilities, check for latest windows updates, downloaded IE update restarted the computer so it could take effect.This is a Sony Vaio Touch Screen Laptop
I've tried everything that I could from these suggestions:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-crashes-stops-working#ie=ie-11
Please advise.

Comment: Does the browser work properly if you use a different user account?

Comment: Check for disk/file system corruption. Use system restore to go back to a point before the power outage.  does it work as expected in Safe Mode?  How about in Normal Mode but running IE with "No add-ons"?

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the IE-Cache and Cookies.

```
del "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*.*" /S /Q
del "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies\*.*" /S /Q
```

An then start ie with:

```
iexplore.exe -nohangrecovery
```

Comment: I'm glad I found you post. This is the only thing that fixed the issue for me. Thank you!